# Where is Webform Component Tab in Drupal 7 Webfrom Module?

Tags: forms, module, drupal-7, components, drupal-webform

i want to make a custom form in drupal 7 which should contain fields like firstname,lastname, date of birth, phone, email and other fields. i download the webform module, install and enable it.

I saw in a video tutorial that there is a Form Component Tab from which we can create our form fields. But when i try to create a form it will not show me the form components tab. i find it every where but no form component tab. can any body plz help me so that i can create my custom form

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same problem today. Didn't see the sub-tab containing [ ***Form Components** ***E-mails** ***Form Settings**] under Webform.

This happens when your theme is a little buggy or the Drupal 7 link overlay hides them.

Solution:

- Try using webform by disabling the overlay (in the module section), or
- Change your theme to Garland or Bartik for ADMIN AREA only.

Hope this helps!